# Change Magento URL category Rules

Tags: magento-enterprise, category, url, seo, catalog-rules

I'm trying to modify URL-Category Rules, from Category Hierarchy-Oriented rules to Seo-Oriented rules.

So i need to change URLs in this way.

From:

`- Root-Category (URL: /rootcategory.html )`

`-- Sublevel category --> /rootcateogory/sublevelcategory.html`

`--- 3rd level Category --> /rootcategory/sublevelcategory/3rdlevelcategory.html`

To:

`- Root-Category (URL: /rootcategory.html )`

`-- Sublevel category --> /sublevelcategory.html`

( *without First level cateogory url key* )

`--- 3rd level Category --> /sublevelcategory/3rdlevelcategory.html`

( *without First level cateogory url key* )

I'm in trouble whit Magento Admin configurations but it seems there is no way to do this.

Do i have to build a Magento Plugin ?

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

I'm running Magento EE ver. 1.13.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Thats a pretty hard one.

You will either need to rewrite the whole url index generation, or you introduce an additional router which resolves your own url schema.

Read this link to get a basic idea of how to:
* http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

Answer (score 3):

**The code below is tested on CE-1.7.0.2. It should work for EE1.12. It looks like it doesn't work for EE-1.13.**
The url of a category is determined by the `url_path` attribute of that category.
So you need to change the way that `url_path` is generated when adding a new category.
For that you need to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::getCategoryRequestPath` and change this line:

```
$requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
```

into this one:

```
if (in_array($category->getLevel(), array(2, 3))){
    $requestPath = $urlKey.$categoryUrlSuffix;
}
else {
    $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
}
```

This means that for level 2 and 3 categories (that are actually level 1 and 2 in the menu) you don't add in front of the url key the parent path.
The url path for the level 2 and 3 categories will consist only of the url_key you enter manually in the admin and the suffix (`.html`).

But there is a catch. This will only work for the new categories you add. The old ones will still have the classic path `parent/child/grandchild.html`.
TO change this behavior run the following code **before** adding new categories.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('level', array('gt'=>2));

foreach ($collection as $category){
    $path = $category->getUrlPath();
    $parts = explode('/', $path);
    if (count($parts) > 1){
        unset($parts[0]);
        $path = implode('/', $parts);
    }
    $category->setUrlPath($path);
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/url')->saveCategoryAttribute($category, 'url_path');
}
```

The code above will change the url path for the existing categories in the desired format.
Rebuild your indexes and everything will look as you want.

You will even get 301 redirects for the existing categories from `parent/child/grandchild.html` to `child/grandchild.html`

**Note:** backup your database just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to code your solution. I rewrote `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::getCategoryRequestPath` but it is not called when New Sub Category is saved. In what database table should i check if the changes are done ?

Comment: @alesdario. You should check the category menu on frontend. it's easier that way. Also make sure you reindexed the flat category after adding a category if the index is set on 'manual'. I tested the solution and it worked for me.

Comment: I don't know why Magento doesn't go through `getCategoryRequestPath` . I'm sure i'm wrong some where but i don't know where. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url` is rewritten right, i've checked it with `get_class(Mage::getModel('catalog/url'));`

Comment: @alesdario. This is strange indeed. I tested the code above and it worked.

Comment: i'll keep you aware. I'm using Magento EE , does it matter?

Comment: @alesdario hmmm...you might be on to something there. If it's ee 1.12 or lower it should work. I'm not sure about ee 1.13 though. a lot has been changed there regarding the url rewrites. Maybe you should state the version in the question. Others may have some experience with that.

Comment: Done. I'm running Magento EE ver. 1.13.1.0

Comment: @alesdario. I don't have a EE1.13 code to test on. I edited my answer and stated that this works on CE 1.7 (and EE1.12). Sorry I cannot do more. Maybe you can find the code that generated the category url path in EE1.13 and follow a similar logic as described in the answer to make it work