# Access Magento Root Category URL

Tags: category, home

From a default Magento install you are provided with a default category (a root category) and this usually has category ID 2.
How can I access the root category page using this as a URL: `http://example.com/catalog/category/view/id/2`. This always 404.

The reason for this is because I want to make this the homepage (without having to go do any CMS layout updates) using system config `web/default/front` as `catalog/category/view/id/2`.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462453/magento-get-the-root-category-url and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14572/change-magento-url-category-rules

Answer (score 1):

As part of the category controller action Magento validates the category against the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category` function `canShow()`.

This will return false against the check against `isInRootCategoryList()`. This function goes and checks the category's parent ids against the store root category id:

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
return in_array($rootCategoryId, $category->getParentIds());
```